# Working example of celery with mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, celery

I'm new to celery, and am working on running asynchronous tasks using Celery.

1. I want to save the results of my tasks to MongoDB.
2. I want to use the AMQP broker.

Celery project examples didn't help me much. Can anyone point me to some working examples?

Answer (score 6):

To use MongoDB as your backend store you have to explicitly configure Celery to use MongoDB as the backend.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/mongodb.html#broker-mongodb

As you said the documentation does not show a complete working example. I just started playing with Celery but have been using MongoDB. I created a short  working tutorial using MongoDB and Celery  http://skillachie.com/?p=953

However these snippets should contain all you need to get a hello world going with Celery and MongoDB

celeryconfig.py

```
 from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "jobs", 
    "taskmeta_collection": "stock_taskmeta_collection",
}

#used to schedule tasks periodically and passing optional arguments 
#Can be very useful. Celery does not seem to support scheduled task but only periodic
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-minute': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
        'args': (1,2),
    },
}
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
import time 

#Specify mongodb host and datababse to connect to
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/jobs'

celery = Celery('EOD_TASKS',broker=BROKER_URL)

#Loads settings for Backend to store results of jobs 
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(30)
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been testing RabbitMQ as a broker and MongoDB as backend, and MongoDB as both broker and backend. These are my findings. I hope they help someone out there.

Assumption: You have MongoDB running on default settings(localhost:21017)
Setting Environment using conda(you can use whatever package manager)

```
conda update -n base conda -c anaconda
conda create -n apps python=3.6 pymongo
conda install -n apps -c conda-forge celery
conda activate apps
```

Update my conda, create an environment called apps and install pymongo and celery.

**RabbitMQ as a broker and MongoDB as backend**

```
sudo apt install rabbitmq-server
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart 
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

If no errors then rabbitmq out to be running. Lets create tasks in executor.py and call them in runner.py

```
# executor.py
import time
from celery import Celery

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost//'
BACKEND_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/from_celery'
app = Celery('executor', broker=BROKER_URL, backend=BACKEND_URL)

@app.task
def pizza_bot(string:str, snooze=10):
    '''return a dictionary with bot and
    lower case string input
    '''
    print(f'Pretending to be working {snooze} seconds')
    time.sleep(snooze)
    return {'bot':string.lower()}
```

and we call them in runner.py

```
# runner.py
import time
from datetime import datetime

from executor import pizza_bot


def run_pizza(msg:str, use_celery:bool=True):
      
      
      start_time = datetime.now()
      if use_celery: # Using celery
            response = pizza_bot.delay(msg)
      else: # Not using celery
            response = pizza_bot(msg)

      print(f'It took {datetime.now()-start_time}!'
            ' to run')
      print(f'response: {response}')

      return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
      # Call using celery
      response = run_pizza('This finishes extra fast')
      while not response.ready():
            print(f'[Waiting] It is {response.ready()} that we have results')
            time.sleep(2) # sleep to second
      print('\n We got results:')
      print(response.result)
```

Run celery on terminal A:

```
cd path_to_our_python_files
celery -A executor.app worker --loglevel=info
```

This is done in development only. I wanted to see what was happening in the background. In production, run it in daemonize.

Run runner.py on terminal B:

```
cd path_to_our_python_files
conda activate apps
python runner.py
```

In terminal A, you will see that the task is received and in snooze seconds it will be completed. On your MongoDB, you will see a new collection called from_celery, with the message and results.

**MongoDB as both broker and backend**

A simple modification was needed to set this. As mentioned, I had to create a config file to set MongoDB backend settings.

```
#mongo_config.py
#Backend Settings
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "celery", 
    "taskmeta_collection": "pizza_collection",
}
```

Let's create executor_updated.py which is pretty much the same as executor.py but the broker is now MongoDB and backend is added via *config_from_object*

```
# executor_updated.py
import time
from celery import Celery

BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/celery'
app = Celery('executor_updated',broker=BROKER_URL)

#Load Backend Settings
app.config_from_object('mongo_config')

@app.task
def pizza_bot(string:str, snooze=10):
    '''return a dictionary with bot and
    lower case string input
    '''
    print(f'Pretending to be working {snooze} seconds')
    time.sleep(snooze)
    return {'bot':string.lower()}
```

Run celery on terminal C:

```
cd path_to_our_python_files
celery -A executor_updated.app worker --loglevel=info
```

Run runner.py on terminal D:

```
cd path_to_our_python_files
conda activate apps
python runner.py
```

Now we have both MongoDB as broker and backend. In MongoDB, you will see a collection called *celery* and a table *pizza_collection*

Hope this helps in getting you started with these awesome tools.

Comment: I have tried the same example but results are not getting saved in MongoDB.