# Celery with Mongodb as brocker and backend

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, django-celery

I followed the code from the below
[Working example of celery with mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740755/working-example-of-celery-with-mongo-db)
Getting the below error

```
CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'collection_names' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.")
```

.
Can someone tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pymongo version 3 should fix the error.